# multiple sidekiq queue for an sinatra application

Tags: ruby, redis, sinatra, sidekiq

We have a Ruby on Sinatra application. We use sidekiq and redis for queue process.

We already implemented and using sidekiq that queues up jobs that does insertion into database. it works pretty fine till now.

Now I wanted to add another jobs which will read bulk data from database and export to csv file.

I donot want both this job to be in same queue instead is there possible to create different queue for these jobs in same application?

Please give some solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need advanced queue options. Read about them here: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options

Create `csv` queue from command line (it can be done in config file as well):

```
sidekiq -q csv -q default
```

Then in your worker:

```
class CSVWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options :queue => :csv

  # perform method
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your great information. Good to know this. I am just curious that how will the jobs get processed from two different queues? are they processed in parallel ?

Comment: Yes. And not only different queue are processed in parallel. By default there are 25 jobs in a single queue, each of them executed in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at sidekiq wiki: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options

by default everything goes inside 'default' queue but you can specify a queue in your worker:

```
 sidekiq_options :queue => :file_queue
```

and to tell sidekiq to process your queue, you have to either declare it in configuration file:

```
:queues:
  - file_queue
  - default
```

or pass it as argument to the sidekiq process: `sidekiq -q file_queue`